# How to test a method using Eclipse? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

So i have coded a method on eclipse (java), and I want to test if it works correctly, how do I do this, because the program won't run unless it has a main header.

So I guess what im asking is how do i use a method in another code

Comment: Can you provide some code that you used...?

Comment: Use JUnit: http://junit.org/

Answer (score 1):

Well if your method is static you can access it via it's class name, if its a member of the class you have to create a instance of the class and call it using the instance.
Let's say we have this class and we want to call both methods in another class:

```
public class ClassToTest {

    public static void staticMethodToTest(){
        //Some code
    }

    public void memberMethodToTest(){
        //Some code
    }
}
```

To test them you can create another class:

```
public class MyClass {
    //Create a main method so you can run your code
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Call static method
        ClassToTest.staticMethodToTest();

        //Call member
        //Create instance of class
        ClassToTest classToTestInstance = new ClassToTest();
        //Call method on instance
        classToTestInstance.memberMethodToTest();

    }
}
```

In the case that both classes are in different packages you have to import the `ClassToTest` using `import package.name.ClassToTest;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to test the internal workings of your program, you can do this by either creating a temporary `main()` method, or by using JUnit testing.

You can accomplish this simply by doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Test it here
}
```

and you should be able to just comment it out/remove it if it works.

Comment: tried that it didn't work. i think u didnt understand question mb, im asking how to use a method in another code.

Comment: Is the method public or private? We need more information to help you.

Comment: So in a new class just create a new object of the class you want to test, and do thisObject.thisMethod();

Answer (score 0):

```
//Have the method declared inside a class.
public MyClass(){
 public String myString(String m){
   return m;
 }
}
//Create another class for your main method and inherit from MyClass   

public MainClass extends MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args){
//Create an object obj from MyClass() 
  //and call the method on the object
     MyClass obj = new MyClass();
     System.out.println(obj.myString("hello"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the method in another class, and give it a constructor so that it can be instantiated. In your main class, make an instance of the class and call your method from it.